# initctl won't start jobs

Tags: server, init

I am operating an Ubuntu 11.10 server and one of the PHP scripts calls a bash script for inserting jobs and starting them.

The script copies the job into `/etc/init`

Everything is fine except that the jobs don't get started with

```
sudo /sbin/initctl start my-tiny-job
```

(I think the reason is unknown job)

When I run the bash script by hand:

```
php-user$ ./bashscript.sh
```

then it works! So this means the job file is correct.

Since this is a functionality called from a web interface I really need to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to AU Michael, glad you got it solved, the way this site works is for you to post your solution as an answer and then click the accept button, this marks it as solved. I'll roll this back and then you can just copy and paste from the editing history.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 13.10 and I met same trouble. Please try `initctl` command in console. To enter console session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login. For me it succeeded this way!

Answer (score 9):

(*Answered by OP*)

> Got it myself! when new jobs are inserted into /etc/init then the update is not noticed until the next check. Myscript is at lot faster then check frenquence so the update needs to be initiation ny hand:
>
> `sudo initctl reload-configuration`
>
> Now it works as expected.